# Set group ownership and permission for new created files/folders

Tags: permissions, apache2, files, ownership

I found several questions like that of mine, but none of them worked for me.

I have a site folder */var/www/afos2.local/html*.
Apache is running under *www-data* user.
I have created a group *site_afos2*. I created a user *afos2*. Added user *afos2* to the group *site_afos2*. For */var/www/afos2.local/html* I set group owner = *site_afos2* and folder owner = *afos*.
The task is to make that when any file/folder created by running a web page will have the owner = *site_afos2* and file/folder owner = *afos*.

Comment: To confirm, you want files created by Apache to be `afos:site_afos2` rather than `www-data:www-data`?

Comment: @matigo , yes, exactly